# STM32 oscillator calculations advice and review

Tags: stm32, oscillator

Can someone please check the below to see whether I'm on the right track and perhaps advise if there is something I should be doing.

## STM32F1 HSE

- gm = 25 mA/V
- I(drive) = 1 mA
- CL1/CL2 recommended = 5 - 25 pF

## XTAL

- 25 MHz
- Cl = 12 pF
- Co = 7 pF
- ESR 50 Ω
- Drive Level 1-200 μW (100 μW typ.)

## Calculations

I've done the following calculation to work out the Cload capacitors assuming 5 pF stray capacitance, as this appears to be the general value around the forums.

C1/C2 = (Cl - 5(stray)) · 2
= 14 pF

Now working out the gain margin which seems fine:

gm_crit = 4 x ESR x (2 Pi F)2 x (Co + Cl)2
= 4 x 50 x 2.468e16 x 3.61e-22
= 1.78 mA/V

g_margin = 25 / 1.78 = 14.04

Below formulas came from https://hoani.net/posts/blog/2017-01-19-oscillator-design/

DL(est) = (ESR x (Pi x F x 2Cl)2 x (VCC)2) / 2
= (50 x 0.000003554 x 10.89) / 2
= 0.0009675 = 967 uW <-- Too High

### Method 2

C(total) = CL1 + (C(stray)/2)
= 14 + (5/2)
= 16.5 pF

DL(est) = (ESR x (Pi x F x Ctot)2 x (VCC)2) / 2
= (50 x 0.000001679 x 10.89) / 2
= 0.000457 = 457 μW <-- Still too high

Looking at the above, it would appear that if the calculations are good then I would also require an external resistor of some value to limit the current to the oscillator. I just have no idea how to calculate that.

In addition, I have the following PCB design based on what I've researched to be best practice, does it look OK? X2 is a 32.768 oscillator (that's another story). Each oscillator circuit has a ground plane with one via going to ground near the MCU. The bottom layer is blank under the oscillator circuit.

[image]

Comment: So what is the problem if it does not work? Also, why did you choose a 25 MHz crystal? That's about the highest frequency the HSE supports and thus most difficult to get working. Why not for example 8 MHz?

Comment: The ‘ground plane’ is only a gnd fill. The ground plane should be underneath the circuit. You would want more vias on your ground fill so it is not an antenna.

Comment: What's the motivation behind this question? Something being somewhat underwhelming is meaningless in this context.

Comment: I chose a 25MHz crystal because that is what has been used in the development board, and yes, it IS the highest frequency the HSE supports.

Comment: @Kartman I'll look at the additional vias on the PCB, thank you.
I'm interested in the calculations as I've not had to work these parameters out before and I'm unsure if it's correct or not.